# Nyquist plot in python control system toolbox

Tags: python, plot

My OS is Windows 10 64 bit, and I've installed the anaconda3 with Python 3.5 integrated. 
In the Jupyter QtConsole, when I tried to do frequency domain analysis using the control system toolbox instead of plotting the graph, the system output the values of the plot. The code I used was:

```
import control
sys=control.ss("1. -2; 3. -4", "5.; 7", "6. 8", "9.")
control.nyquist_plot(sys, omega=None, Plot=True, color='b', labelFreq=0)
```

The output was a bunch of arrays with numbers which were values of the plot. And the Nyquist was not shown.

Can anybody tell me what I was doing wrong in trying to plot the Nyquist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the trick is:

```
 %matplotlib qt
```

Which plot the graph in a new figure window.